# in a Typescript Class, what are the "executable area" besides constructor() and ngOninit()?

Tags: angular, typescript, class

I'm learning Angular, sometimes I try to execute a method, and I receive an error message which says I'm out of the executable area. Then I place it inside the constructor of the class or ngOinit method and workds, but, are these good practices? Are these the only areas to execute functions within a Typedcript Class?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample that produces such an error.

Comment: Honestly sounds like you don't understand enough about OO programming. Angular classes are structured similar to OO, with classes, constructors, properties, etc. You need to read up on it.

Comment: In your case the `ngOnInit` or the constructor of the class would be the executable areas. Outside of the methods like those you can declare and define properties but not actually call the methods.

Probably you want to create other methods inside your class and call those from within the `ngOnInit`. Or if you have if you have a reference to your class call a public method directly. 

But like @theblindprophet said it would be good to read up on this. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with you all guys... I am a self learner, I learn this just for hobby... I took your advice and  already started to read up on heavy OOP tutorials... That's the best way to start.. : )

Comment: The constructor should be reserved for things such as the services which you use in the class and ngOnInit essentially will call all the functions within it as soon as the page initialises / reloads. You can place functions outside of this but they will need to be called by the user pressing a button within the template, etc.